# How to animate the removal of a PageView.Builder item dynamically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is it possible to animate the removal of an item in a horizontal PageView.Builder in flutter?

I know there's the AnimatedList but I have been trying to do it on a PageView.Builder as I need a PageView.Builder for my use-case.

I want to make it so once a user presses on an Item from the PageView the item gets removed with an animation. Not Dismissable, but on press.

I would really love if you could point me out to the correct documentation or example.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is *still* not a proper way to do this. You can try combining `SlideTransition` with `animateToPage` method of the `PageController`. But it will not be ideal. It would be optimal if there was a `AnimatedListView` kind of version for the `PageView`. Or at least a good way to mimic it.